# does using different relative paths for the same resource get cached by the browser just once?

Tags: php, html, caching, path, relative-path

My question might not be clear, so here is an example.

I have a PHP script that will auto add the relative path to all of HTML resources like

- CSS - `<link href href="<?php echo $siteroot ?>css/main.css" ... >`
- JS - `<script src="<?php echo $siteroot ?>js/main.js"</script>`
- Images `<img src="<?php echo $siteroot ?>img/avatar.jpg" ... >`
- other uses like PHP includes

the script will auto make the relative path to the site root and this will vary to be '../', '../../', '../../../', or an empty string '' if it is the site root folder - main index

My question does this will affect the cache system the browser uses? I thought of this because the same resource will be different in many pages that are in subfolders!

once ../../img/avatar.jpg other ../img/avatar.jpg, other img/avatar.jpg alone!

I have tried with chrome and run a file with img and then deleting the img and opening a file in a subfolder. This worked and the image was there!

I still not sure and want a granted answer about the caching process for relative paths. If there is any extra information, I will appreciate it :)

Thank you

Comment: I would also try to verify this with the Network tab of browser debuggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These resources will be cached once because absolute path is same, regardless they relative paths differ. Browsers uses absolute paths for caching.

Comment: Thank you @ponury-kostek this was a quick and informative answer. I didn't know that absolute paths get cached. :)